# UICollectionView not getting rendered

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

This code has UICollectionView getting initiated and datasource being assigned. Cells are supposed to be rendered however the cells are not getting rendered.
The DataSource is extracted out in this case.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        let dataSource = DateSource()

        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}

class DateSource:NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 80.0
    let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 7.0
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    private let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = (screenSize.width-leftAndRightPaddings)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 8, bottom: 5, right: 8)
    }
}
```

But this code renders the cells, when the datasource is sort of merged in the ViewController

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

private let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"
let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 80.0
let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 7.0
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        let dataSource = self

        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = (screenSize.width-leftAndRightPaddings)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 8, bottom: 5, right: 8)
    }
}
```

I am a little lost here, was something to be instantiated inside DataSource, which was missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, you've instantiated datasource in `viewDidLoad()`,

```
let dataSource = DateSource()
```

This restricts the lifespan of your datasource object within the scope of that method. You need to declare your datasource as a member of your View Controller, as such;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let dataSource = DateSource()
    private let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
...
..
}
```

Second snippet works since the datasource is self and it's scope will outlive the collectionView's.

Comment: Is there a way to check if there is a memory problem ? @rmaddy

Comment: @MuditTuli What memory problem are you talking about?

Comment: @rmaddy I meant, how can I check the lifespan of the object ? if this is being destroyed.
For instance this code https://gist.github.com/mudittuli/ce80c7d27ef0f0d90efa2438d3b15208 is also not rendering the collectionView

Comment: @MuditTuli You need to understand how memory management and object lifecycle works. That's far too broad of a topic to put in comments. Read the [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48) chapter in the Swift book.